# Indicating jump links UI wireframe

Tags: website-design, wireframe

I hope this is the right forum.

I am drawing out a wireframe for a web developer to follow, indicating the layout of a website. 
I want to draw this out by hand, using the best practices/layout that a Wordpress web developer would find most useful.

I have a homepage which is long-scrolling. Some elements on the top navigation bar menu take the user through to a separate page, but some of the elements are jump links to areas on the homepage further down (alternatively viewed by scrolling down).

How should I indicate this on my wireframe (this is hand-drawn, just a simplified sketch)? I don't want to cause confusion just going with my gut and start drawing out lines and boxes that indicate something different, in common wireframe practice, to what I am trying to illustrate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is probably best done with annotations**

If the number of annotations get too robust for your sketch you can always sketch the menu(s) separately to include them as an addendum. Feel free to replace “content” "links" “page” with actual locations.

*Bonus: if you can draw the arrows pointing directly to content in the page(s). You’ll have made yourself a wire flow.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark. Glad to see it's a project dependant process, I wasn't sure if there was some 'done' way to communicate it all.